# What does the following sentence mean? Could anyone please explain its organisation to me?

Tags: meaning, sentence-construction, conditional-constructions

> For example, were all politicians to fully disclose every personal foibles, character flaw, and detail concerning personal life, few honest politicians would ever by elected.

[Source](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=VGvDHjE8deEC&pg=PA73&lpg=PA73&dq=politicians%20to%20fully%20disclose%20every%20personal%20foible&source=bl&ots=h45B3KLr65&sig=JGBIRk-BM-e7rNcE2hIkNJZorQM&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi-_7-o1IrQAhWEthoKHfEdC3wQ6AEIGzAA#v=onepage&q=politicians%20to%20fully%20disclose%20every%20personal%20foible&f=false): *GRE Answers to the Real Essay Questions*

Comment: This sentence is not grammatical; it has at least four major errors. Have you transcribed it correctly?

Comment: If all politicians did (A), (B), and (C), (D) would not happen.

Comment: I haven't transcribed it myself, i have just copied it for a source. I could sense that there is some connection between 'were','to' and 'would' , but i couldnt figure out meaning. Also i cant recognise those errors you mentioned.Could you please elaborate.

Comment: The writer is getting confused on the *semantic* front. If all politicians fully disclosed everything, that implies ***all*** politicians would be honest. But if few [honest] politicians then got elected, what would we call the people we ***did*** elect? We couldn't call them *dishonest* politicians, since we're hypothesising a situation where such people don't exist.

Comment: @StoneyB that is *exactly* how it is written. This time a text was correctly copied, although the beginning "For example," had been omitted.

Comment: Errors: 1) *every* requires singular *foible*, not plural *foibles* 2) all politicians do not have a single personal life between them--*life* should be *lives* 3) *personal lives* requires a determiner, presumably *their* 4) *ever by elected* is meaningless--this should be *ever **be** elected*

Answer (score 2):

The sentence could be rewritten as

"**If** all politicians were to fully disclose every personal foible<strike>**s**</strike>, character flaw, and detail concerning personal life, (**then**) few honest politicians would ever **be** elected"

It's a way to create an if-then sentence without actually saying either of those words.

Another example is "Had I known before that it would be this cold, I would have brought a jacket."

That sentence means the exact same thing as "If I had known before that it would be this cold, (then) I would have brought a jacket."

It's important to note that you can only start this sentence structure with an auxiliary verb (i.e. you can't say "Knew I before that it would be this cold")

Comment: thanks for reply. Is following similar to the sentence given above "Were it not for you the boy would be drowned."

Comment: That's the main idea. A couple of things I would change in your sentence are placing a comma after "you" and changing "be" to "have". "Would be drowned" is grammatically correct, but it is not the correct wording for this meaning.

Comment: The citation is copied correctly now.

Answer (score 1):

If every politician was supposed to tell the public every small shortcoming/flaw, and every detail of their personal life, few politicians could win an election by being honest.